# The frequency function for $Y_t-18=0.4X_t+0.9X_{t-1}+e_t$

Tags: fourier-transform, transfer-function, frequency-response, random-process, stochastic

I am having trouble finding the frequency function that takes me from $X_t$ to $Y_t$ in the system stated in the title. $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are stationary stochastic processes and $e_t$ is zero mean white noise. If I didn't have $-18$ and the white noise it would be $H(f)= 0.4 + 0.9e^{-i2\pi f}$, but with them I am not really sure. Thanks

Comment: The system is not LTI.

Comment: When you say "frequency function", do you mean the frequency _spectrum_?  Is $X_t$ given?  If not, then you have one equation in two unknowns.  @Hilmar: it's not LTI, but it's affine, so one can still use LTI analysis tools for part of it.